# Mobile Optimization for HTML blog

Tags: html, css, blogs

I have a baseball blog that I made using HTML, and things are going really well. I have a problem, though. Whenever I do a google search for my blog (Yawkey Talk), this comes up:

[image: Search result]

I don't want my name to show up, and I'm not sure why it's showing up. I would like to know if there is anything I can do to eliminate my name. Also I would like to know if there is something I can do so that when a person searches a key word (eg: red sox, blog, yawkey, etc.) Any help will we appreciated.

Comment: Check your `<title>`.

Comment: about the keywords, add this inside the head tags: `<meta name=keywords content="red sox, blog, yawkey" />`